# In static block call .phtml file for specific product id

Tags: product, magento-1, static-block

I have a template which uses banners on the homepage,these banners get filled by a static block like the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <a href="{{store url=''}}women.html">
    <img src="{{skin url='images/banner-3.jpg'}}" alt="" />
    <span class="s-desc">
        <span>
            <h1>Product ABC</h1>
            <h2>$99,99</h2>
            <span class="banners-button">Buy Now</span>
        </span>
    </span>
    </a>
</div>
```

This is static however as I need to put in the image and write down the product name and so on by hand. What I would like to to from the stativ block is something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    {{block type="core/template" name="product_id" pid="1" template="myfolder/product_id.phtml"}}
</div>
```

And then have a .phtml file where I get the product ID from the static block as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->getPid();?>
```

and then create the input for the banner there, so that I can just change the pid in the static block, because as far as I know **I cannot get the image, product price and name of a product and URL in a static block or not**?

**UPDATE**

I also would need to pass on a flag to the template file to differentiate between two types of products and the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you know those data you can definitely do something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    {{block type="core/template" name="product_id" pid="1" pimage="imageurl" template="myfolder/product_id.phtml"}}
</div>
```

Then call

```
<?php echo $this->getPimage(); ?>
```

But that would be **painful and you will have to change several arguments each time you use that block for a different product**.

What you can do is **get those data directly in your template using the pid**:

Either by loading the product (not recommended, loading an entire product to get just a few attributes is very bad in terms of performance):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getPid());
$_productImage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
$_productName = $_product->getName();
$_productPrice = $_product->getPrice();
```

Or using a collection (more code but way better in terms of performance):

```
$_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
    ->joinAttribute('image', 'catalog_product/image', 'entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $this->getPid())
    ->setPageSize(1);

if ($_collection->getSize()) {
    $_product = $_collection->getFirstItem();
    $_productImage = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
    $_productName = $_product->getName();
    $_productPrice = $_product->getPrice();
}
```

Comment: So if i would need the image, name and price which would be the best way? At the end I will call this template file 3 times for 3 different banners.

Comment: @Klettseb see my updated code, I would personally go for the collection solution

Comment: Ok i will give it a try now ;-) Thanks a lot for the answer, i will go for the collection to keep the performance in mind :-)

Comment: Ok product comes up works like a charm so far, two more simple questions, to add the URL, but only the relative one to the store URL, can I use getProductUrl();? And is there a way I can pass another value on to the template file, somehow like a flag to differentiate between two types?

Comment: @Klettseb yeah you can pass as many values as you want to the template file ;) if you also need the product URL just add `->addAttributeToSelect('product_url')` to the collection ;)

Comment: But not anything random or? Like type="1" or type="2" I assume

Comment: @Klettseb well it's obviously safer to use something custom to ensure it's not already used by Magento somewhere

Comment: Thanks ! Really helped me here, was on the right path but I guess performance wise this is so much better !

Comment: @Klettseb you're welcome ;)

Comment: last question, i have 8 different images for a product, how can i get a specific one out of them ? I know how to get small, thumb and base but is there a way to get another one?

Comment: @Klettseb hmmm by comment it ain't easy, please post a new question I'll check that out ;)